# ExpandableListView - OnChildTouchListener

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to create a drag-drop interface for a ExpandableListView. 
I wanted to know if there is a function similar to OnChildClickListener for OnTouch?

If not, what would be the best way of listening for a touch event on a child inside the expandable list?

Comment: That method name. :O "On Child Touch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized we could add an OnTouchListener() in getChildView(). That would listen for a touch event every time the user touches the child item.